# Just downloaded the nautilus source code, but some files seem to be missing

Tags: nautilus, source-code

I just ran the command `apt-get source nautilus` and it saved the code in my home area.

I have been looking through the files (well, grepping) and there are comments like this one (takes from lines 3691 to 3693, in file `/po/en_GB.po`:

```
#: ../src/nautilus-places-sidebar.c:519
msgid "Recent files"
msgstr "Recent files"
```

That looks like it is referencing the file `nautilus-places-sidebar.c` in `../src` (so /src from the main dir with the source code it - `nautilus-13.10.1`), but in `nautilus-13.10.1/src` there is no file `nautilus-places-sidebar.c`.

Why is this - am I interpreting the comment wrong or is the comment incorrect, or what?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be better to fork the source code from Gnome GIT: git://git.gnome.org/nautilus, or the [git website](https://github.com/ecanuto/nautilus/).

The source package is needed just to build the current version of an package. This can differ from original sources.

Comment: So will it not have all the files in the `apt-get source` one?

Comment: Correct. The official sources are here: git://git.gnome.org/nautilus I will upgrade my answer.

Answer (score 0):

In fact, the problem is that sidebar sources has been moved to gtk+3.0. Сomments just were left as is. This particular file now in gtk/gtkplacessidebar.c.